# How to solve$(2xy^2-3y^3)dx+(7-3xy^2)dy=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve the following differential equation?
$$(2xy^2-3y^3)dx+(7-3xy^2)dy=0.$$
I solved it by using change of variable $y=z^\alpha$ but I'm looking for other ways to solve it.

Comment: You want to prove??? Maybe to solve? I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to look for an integrating factor since if you rewrite (by dividing both sides with $y^2$) the equation as $(2x-3y)dx+(7y^{-2}-3x)dy=0$, then your equation becomes exact one. Also, actually this means that $y^{-2}$ is the integrating factor.:)